# Formulating a pure sine wave into a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

sorry for any confusion, I am a graduate chemist and my undergraduate math classes were a long time ago.

For an electrochemistry problem (3c.), we were asked to convert two sine waves and the ratio of both to an complex representation of the form:

$ z=\widehat{z}e^{jφ_{z}}$

[image]

My problem is, that I don't know how to convert a sine *function* itself into a complex number with Euler representation, as it contains a variable; I am a bit lost here. Or is it not possible and I just need to reformulate the values gathered in 3b.? I found a website that did a similar problem, but I didn't understand one step in particular. Anyone got an idea?

https://firmfunda.com/maths/complex-number/algebra-of-complex-numbers/modeling-sine-waves-complex-arithmetic

[image]

I understand the first step, but why does cos(wx) necessarily be the same as isin(wx)?